# Why reading propert("text") from TextEdits from GridLayout always returns value that is in cell(0,0)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml, qt6

This qml code, generates grid layouted filled with random values

```
GridLayout {
    id: month
    objectName: "month"
    height: Screen.height - 500
    width: Screen.width - 300
    rows: 16
    columns: numberOfDays
    columnSpacing: 0
    rowSpacing: 0
    x: 150
    y: 350

    Repeater {
        model: month.rows * month.columns
        id: monthR

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: month.width / month.columns
            height: month.height / month.rows

            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            color: saturdays.includes(index % month.columns) ? "lightblue" : ( sundays.includes(index % month.columns) ? "pink" : (index >= month.columns * 8 && index < month.columns * 9 ? "lightgrey" : "white"))
            TextEdit {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: index >= month.columns * 8 && index < month.columns * 9 ? "-" : Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
                readOnly: index >= month.columns * 8 && index < month.columns * 9
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                font.pixelSize: 25
            }
        }
    }
}
```

c++

```
QObjectList children = rootObject->children();
    QQuickItem *gridLayout = nullptr;
    for (QObject *child : children) {
        if (child->objectName() == "month") {
            gridLayout = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(child);
            qDebug() << gridLayout;
        }
    }
    qDebug() << gridLayout->childAt(0,0)->children().at(0)->property("text");
    qDebug() << gridLayout->childAt(0,1)->children().at(0)->property("text");
    qDebug() << gridLayout->childAt(0,2)->children().at(0)->property("text");
    qDebug() << gridLayout->childAt(0,3)->children().at(0)->property("text");
```

no matter what I try value readen is always from childAt(0,0)

Instructions below return:

```
 qDebug() << gridLayout->children() ----- QList(QQuickRepeater(0x25929912640), QQuickScreenAttached(0x25929b1df00), QQuickLayoutAttached(0x2592c8a5da0))


qDebug() << gridLayout->childAt(0,0)->children(); ------QList(QQuickPre64TextEdit(0x25929b45c50), QQuickPen(0x25929b1f6c0), QQuickLayoutAttached(0x2592c8a6340))
```

I try different ways to read those values

Comment: The input parameters for the `Item.childAt` function aren't `row` and `column` indexes; but, they are `x` and `y` coordinates. The function returns the child at the `point(x, y)`. Which for small numbers, the result will always be the first child. To get `child[i][j]`, try this: `children[i * columns + j]` or use a table view and model.